# Error unique constraint and during execution of trigger oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have form in which user add information of new born baby with his/her head family name. When add information into table then getting following errors

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (PK) violated
ORA-06512: at trigger_name, line 21
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger
```

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DB_NAME"."TRG_NBB" 
AFTER INSERT ON baby
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (new.status = 'A') DECLARE
 v_1 tab_1.col_1%type;
 v_2 tab_2.col_2%type;
 v_3 tab_2.col_3%type;
 v_4 tab_2.col_4%type;
 v_5 tab_2.col_5%type;
 v_6 date;
 newmofid number;

BEGIN
 select max(nvl(col_2,0))+1 into newmofid from tab_2;
 SELECT distinct col_1,col_2,to_char(col,'DD-MM-YYYY') INTO v_1,v_2,v_6
 from table
 where tcid = :new.tcid;

 SELECT col_4,col_5,col_3 into v_4,v_5,v_3
 from tab_2
 where col_1 = v_1
 and col_2 = v_2; 

 INSERT INTO tab_2 (all_columns)
 VALUES(variable_names);

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Born Baby successfully added to member table');
END trg_nbb;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "DB_NAME"."TRG_NBB" ENABLE;
```

When I execute this sql query It's take 4 to 5 seconds and increment in values very quickly

```
select max(nvl(col_2,0))+1 into newmofid from tab_2;
```

Result:

```
6030819791
```

Again execute takes 3 to 4 seconds

Result:

```
6030819798
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is `MAX + 1` that causes problems:

```
select max(nvl(col_2,0))+1 into newmofid from tab_2;
```

Such a principle is in most cases wrong and will fails, especially in a multi-user environment where two (or more) users at the same time fetch the same `MAX + 1` value, do some processing, and - at the time of insert - one of them succeeds (because it is the first), but the rest of them fail because such a value already exists in the table.

I suggest you switch to a **sequence**, e.g.

```
create sequence seq_baby;
```

and then, in your form, do

```
select seq_baby.nextval into newmofid from dual;
```

Comment: This section need to add in trigger?

select seq_baby.nextval into newmofid from dual;

Comment: Yes, instead of `select max(nvl(col_2,0))+1 into newmofid from tab_2;`